# Missing citations - master thesis

Tags: thesis, masters, thesis-committee

I have submitted my Master thesis and noticed that I missed a citation for a figure, and 2 citations were printed as ?, (latex keyword errors) instead of the original citation. and at the end of thesis, we need to write our theses into a paper format and I missed two tables, (my results tables) in the paper.
I didn't notice them when printing and greatly regret this and wasn't intentional. Everything else was fine. They liked my results and everything was good.
Will I fail because of this? Or can I ask my supervisor to give me a chance to revise these. Because the revisions wouldn't take a lot of time and can be done quickly.
(fyi I am in Germany)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt very much you will fail. More likely, one of your examiners will point out the errors and ask that you correct them before whatever final thing (like binding the thesis permanently and submitting a copy to your university library) happens. Examiners are (mostly) not completely stupid and are aware that mistakes happen.

That said, I see little to be lost by telling our supervisor about the mistake, and asking their advice.

Comment: Thank you. I am planning on contacting them on Tuesday when they will be back at their office. The thing is I have submitted a binding copy which is the reason I am panicking.